# Formatting doors table in rpe

Tags: ibm-doors

I want to display a Doors table with a different style for the first row using RPE.
for example, make the first row have a diferent background color, or other border style.

is there any simple way to do that?

Thanks,
Boris.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution was to use a variable called "firstRow" which is Assigned to True in an empty Container before the table, then on the row of the table it is assigned to False.
Then in the background properties I have a script that looks something like:

```
if (firstRow == "True") {
    "SpecialColour";
} else {
    "NormalColour";
}
```

A variation of this script needs to be used for each different property that changes, for example if the first row was centered, with a blue background and bold text, this would need three duplicates of the script. Alternatively if you are exporting to Word you can set a table style in the stylesheet, although I am not quite sure how to explain this without going through it myself again.

Hope that helped!